# Passing Instance before create, in a ForeignKeyField, Django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have two models in these forms:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
   ....

class Children(models.Model):
   parent = ForeignKey('Parent')
   ....
```

when creating a children, i have to pass a Parent as parent, my problem is I want to create the children itself, when I am creating the Parent, just as other fields, like a simple "models.TextField" Can anyone lead me how to do that?

Comment: Well you can't. Just create the parent first, then add the children.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the `__init__()` method of your `Children` models and overwrite the `save()` method of your `Parent` model:

**__init__:**

```
# in class Children()
def __init__(self, parentID):
    self.parent = parentID
    # ...
```

**save:**

```
# in class Parent()
def save(self, ...):
    # do parent save
    # do parent super().save()

    # PSEUDO CODE # 
    if hasChildren:
        for each childen of parent:
            child = Children(self.id) # <-- entails to overwrite the __init__() method in class Children
            child.save()
```

Additionally you need to render the option (children-fields) to create children together with a parent.

If you are using the django-admin interface for this only, you can add inline models to you `parent` `s`modelAdmin`. See the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline)

Answer (score 0):

Add a post save hook to the save method of your `Parent` model.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Parent)
def create_children(sender, **kwargs):
    pass
```

`create_children` will be called any time an instance of `Parent` is saved.

### Reference

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/